# React JS bold the text in between

Tags: reactjs, text, styles

In the below code, I would like to style only some words for chartDesc (for example **"the payback period"**). Either bold or italic etc. Tried regular expressions, did not work. Please help!

```
import React from 'react';
import Pie from './Pie';
import TextTruncate from 'react-text-truncate';
import ReactTooltip from 'react-tooltip';
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router';

export default class Donutchart extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super();
    }

    getElements(id) {
        let backendData = this.props.data;
        let width = 120;
        let height = 120;
        let radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;
        let donutWidth = 15;

        let chartData;
        let chartDesc;
        switch(id) {
            case 'CASH_PURCHASE' :{
               chartData = backendData["financialModelToFinancialSummary"][id];
               const chartDescValue = backendData["financialModelToFinancialSummary"][id];

               chartDesc = `Your estimated Solar Savings over 25 years (after net costs) will be $ ${parseFloat(chartDescValue.savings).toFixed(0)}, the payback period will be ${chartData["roiYear"]} years, and your home will increase in value by $ ${parseFloat(chartDescValue.increaseHomeValue).toFixed(0)}`;
               break;
        }
```

Comment: Where and how are you displaying chartDesc. Do you have control over it's display?

Comment: Where is your render function? Can you include it please

Comment: Below is the render function under TextTruncate tag

`<TextTruncate
                          line={2}
                          truncateText="â€¦"
                          text={chartDesc}
                          textTruncateChild={<a style={{color: chartData.uiData.color}} onClick={this.onDetailClick.bind(this,id)}>more..</a>}
                      />`

Answer (score 0):

You can set `chartDesc` to be a component itself, instead of doing string interpolation.

```
chartDesc = (
  <p>
    Your estimated Solar Savings over 25 years (after net costs) will be $ {parseFloat(chartDescValue.savings).toFixed(0)}, <b>the payback period</b> will be ${chartData["roiYear"]} years, and your home will increase in value by $ ${parseFloat(chartDescValue.increaseHomeValue).toFixed(0)}
  </p>
);
```

(see `<b>` tag in html)

Comment: Only if chartDesc can be used like that. If it is being used as a prop to another component that is treating chartDesc as a string then this would not work

Comment: @TMitchell

Would you please check my comment on how it is being rendered and advise?

Comment: @VinayDS It looks like react-text-truncate is expecting a string, so you won't be able to send a component as described above

Comment: @TMitchell thanks. Any other way to achieve what I need?

Comment: @VinayDS perhaps modify the truncate component to work for you, or find an alternative solution

Comment: Yeah the above will only work if TextTrunate can take a component as text. Cant think of any solution to your problem without editing TextTruncate somehow. using `dangerouslySetInnerHtml` would allow you to take a string but, again, that would requite editing TextTruncate